# How to upload image in a native iOS app built using Mobile SDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

Does the Mobile SDK provide any methods which allow uploading an attachment (image) to Salesforce? I am using 3.0 iOS SDK and building a native app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `requestForUploadFile` method. Try this

- Use the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate
- Set your image source to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`
- Convert image data to NSData and then upload using `SFRest API requestForUploadFile`

Some sample code (may require some tweaks to run though)

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <SFRestDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

- (void) uploadImage {
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    NSData *imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage,0.0);

    SFRestRequest *request =
    [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForUploadFile:imageData
                                                name:@"myimage.png"
                                         description:@"Test Img"
                                            mimeType:@"image/png"];
    [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can I upload a jpg using this?

Comment: Yes, change mimeType:@"image/png"]; to mimeType:@"image/jpg"]; That should be it

Comment: How do I store the uploaded file against a Salesforce Record (Eg: Case)? @user5094